# Looking for the title of a story with a werewolf hitchhiker

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for the title of a story I read in junior high.
There is a driver and he/she picks up a hitchhiker; it is a man in disguise as a woman.  He tells a story about hitch-hikers in the area; the implication is that one of these hitchhikers is a werewolf who has been in the area for a long time.
The story ends (or near the end) as a they see a hitchhiker, and the disguised man asks the driver to stop.

Comment: I remember this one, but I don't remember the title. Not sure it was actually a werewolf or SFF, but let me see if I can find it again

Comment: Think it's "Night Drive" by Will F Jenkins

Comment: Nailed it in one!  Thank you, Radhil!

Comment: I've been looking for that story for years!

Answer (score 2):

The story is "Night Drive" by Will F Jenkins.

The story follows Madge, who receives a call from a Mr. Tabor just before she sets out on an overnight drive to another town. Mr. Tabor asks Madge to take his niece on the drive as well. Madge is uncomfortable, Mr. Tabor lost his wife on that same road, but agrees.

Tabor's niece spends a portion of the drive relaying a tale about a serial killer, and brings up old tales of werewolves as ways such men could disguise their actions. Madge spends the drive building up her fears as she notes details and realizes that the "niece" is actually a man.  There is an opportunity for escape as she sees a fellow traveller having car trouble, and pulls over.

There is a mention of seeing someone's eyes glow, but otherwise the tale of werewolves is completely ambiguous as to whether it was true or not.